# Как правильно указать в SELECT имя таблицы содержащей /

Tags: db2, sap

Пытаюсь посчитать количество строк в таблице /SCWM/ORDIM_C.

```
D:\db2\db2w01\db2_software\BIN>db2 "select count(*) from SAPW01.'/SCWM/ORDIM_C' where LGNUM='W119'"
```

> SQL0104N  An unexpected token "'/SCWM/ORDIM_C'" was found following "ount(*)
>   from SAPW01.".  Expected tokens may include:  "".  SQLSTATE=42601

Как правильно расставить кавычки в этом выражении?

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

```
db2 "select count(*) from SAPW01.\"/SCWM/ORDIM_C\" where LGNUM='W119'"
```